# How to add calling action in update controller (edit user ) in devise gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to call function when user edit his page.

Here is my settings_controller.rb:

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    email_changed = @user.email != params[:user][:email]
    password_changed = !params[:user][:password].empty?
    successfully_updated = if email_changed or password_changed
      @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
    else
      @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
    end

    if successfully_updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      //need to call action here
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end
end
```

I need to redirect user if successful update.

In my routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations', :settings => 'settings'}
```

or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I would recommend looking into devise (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/) for this type of stuff. No sense in reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Beerlington, I need to override settings controller. I will edit question, can you look at my code ? Controller isn't overriding.

Comment: I haven't done anything with devise so I wouldn't be too much help. If it was me though, I would post a new question and make sure you use the devise tag. There are a lot of people asking devise questions on stackoverflow so I know it's a popular gem.

Comment: Your code cries for refactoring.

Comment: I get it from devise/wiki, it is not mine code))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `settings` route in `devise_for`.

Look at [`RegistrationController` in devise.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)

You can overwrite this:

```
class SettingsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 def update
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  email_changed = @user.email != params[:user][:email]
  password_changed = !params[:user][:password].empty?
  successfully_updated = if email_changed or password_changed
    @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
  else
    @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
  end

  if successfully_updated
    # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed
    sign_in @user, :bypass => true
    //need to call action here
  else
    render "edit"
  end
 end
end
```

In routing:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'settings'}
```